# My computer isn't starting anymore

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer isn't booting anymore from when an additional fan was put in the internal side of the removable panel of the case: in the majority of the cases, it blocks in the ASUS presentation screen, else I'm asked if I want to load the installation or load the default settings, then I'm asked if I want to start the Windows boot recovery tool. If I choose yes, it says "loading the necessary files..." and it stucks when the progress bar indicates that the operation is complete; if I choose no, it says "Starting windows" for a few seconds, but then the computer reboots.
I've also tried to boot it without the panel which has the extra fan, but the problem subsists.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Check if all the cables are properly attached. Check if the PSU is strong enough to feed an additional fan.

Comment: @TomWijsman the cables are ok; I forgot to say that the fan is not linked to the computer directly, but it has an external feeder I have to plug to the socket in order to make the fan work, so it shouldn't affect the PSU

Comment: Not an expert in this, but there's two things that jump to mind. A badly designed case, fan, ... could yield static electricity that may have caused damage to other electronics in the computer. You may be using too much in the sockets (since adding the fan) which causes spikes or drops in the power supplied to the computer. Iotw; disconnect everything from the sockets and disconnect everything in the computer, then try to build up a minimal system and see if that works. If it does, something *extra* is broken or power is unstable. If it doesn't, something of the computer is broken or unstable.

Comment: @TomWijsman thanks, I'm trying what you suggested and let you know

Comment: Hmm, since it asks which settings to load at ASUS presentation screen yet another scenario is that the BIOS battery circuit somehow failed to keep the BIOS settings. In this case, the computer may not be booting because some BIOS setting is wrong. You will want to reset the BIOS settings and correctly set them again; one of the more important settings, is to choose the right AHCI mode (often the one option is slow / non-booting, the other is fast / boots).

Comment: @TomWijsman thanks, I'm trying to reset the BIOS settings too

Comment: Bung Win 7 disk in and Startup Repair once you've checked your BIOS settings. You may need to replace the BIOS battery.

Comment: @TomWijsman I've unplugged all cables and replugged just the screen to the case and screen and case to the socket, but now the screen is not receiving the signal from the case

Comment: @BigChris thanks, once I'll be able to get the screen working I'll do what you suggested

Comment: @TomWijsman now the computer with only the screen plugged works, thanks for your help

Comment: @BigChris I've reset the BIOS, now I managed to open the windows boot recovery, thanks for your help